# MDX grouped dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have a dimension  `[product].[type]` having its member containing `'Food','Book','Metal','Meat', etc.` My task is to show a categorized dimension to group my sales value, such as, group `Food & Meat` as `0`, `Metal & Tool` as `1`, `Book` as 2, etc..

My Query seems doesn't work:

```
WITH calculated member [Measures].[Grouped Type] AS
  IIF([product].[type].CurrentMember IS [product].[type].[Meat], 0,
  IIF([product].[type].CurrentMember IS [product].[type].[Food], 0,
  IIF([product].[type].CurrentMember IS [product].[type].[Tool], 1,
  ...... , 9)))))
SELECT {[Measures].[Sales Amount], [Measures].[Grouped Type].Children} on 0
FROM Cube
WHERE ([Condition])
```

It looks my total sales amount is shown, but not correctly categorized. any help? Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calculated members against the product dimension, not measure's one:

```
With
Member [product].[type].[0] as
Sum({[product].[type].[Meat],[product].[type].[Food]})

Member [product].[type].[1] as
Sum({[product].[type].[Tool]})

select 
[Measures].[Sales Amount] on 0,
{[product].[type].[0],[product].[type].[1]} on 1
From Cube
Where ([Condition])
```